# Inserting colon with join function after splitting. PERL

Tags: regex, perl, split

```
my $fruit; 
my $quantity = <STDIN>;
my $results = split(/,|:/,$quantity);
foreach my $result(@results){
    my ($fruit_name, $value) = split("=", @result);
    if($fruit_name == "apple") {
        $fruit = $value;
        my $ratio = join(":", $fruit);
        print "My ratio = $ratio";
     }
}
```

My Output is: My ratio = 12
from the input: apple=1,apple=2.

My output that I wanted:

```
My ratio = 1:2.
```

Thank you for all your helps.

Comment: "_My Output is_" -- output of what?  The posted code is incorrect and certainly wouldn't work (and possibly not compile).  Can you fix it to your actual program?  What is your input for which you expect that output?

Comment: If you only have 1 argument to `join`, you won't get a delimiter. Also, if that is your input, with that code you will not get that output.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: I'm guessing the input is that line `apple=1,apple=2`.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings`. You have two trivial errors in your code that will be hidden otherwise: `Found = in conditional, should be == at foo.pl line 12.
Global symbol "@result" requires explicit package name ...`

Comment: You can't just add `use strict; use warnings` without also fixing the code.

Comment: Thank you, I was just write down the partial but I will leave it back to the original what I posted then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayhaps this is what you are looking to do

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

chomp(my $quantity = <DATA>);               # chomp removes newline from input
my @results = split /[,:]/, $quantity;      # using [] to create a character class
my @nums;
foreach my $result (@results){              
    my ($fruit_name, $value) = split "=", $result;
    if ($fruit_name eq "apple") {           # have to use eq when comparing strings
        push @nums, $value;                 # store value for later printing
    }
}

say "My ratio = ", join ":", @nums;


__DATA__
apple=1,apple=2
```

Output:

```
My ratio = 1:2
```

Your code has these errors.

- The variable `@result` should be `$result`. You would know this if you had `use strict` enabled.
- You use `=` assignment where you wanted to use numerical equality test `==`. Since you did not use `use warnings`, you didn't know about that. Also, you should use `eq` for strings.
- You have a variable `$value`, which you move to `$fruit`, which you move to `$ratio`. This is confusing and pointless.
- You cannot use `join` with just one value. Then it does nothing, as you need at least 2 values to join.
- The output from your code is `My ratio = 1My ratio = 2`, not `My ratio = 12`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. However, is there anyway to get the delimiter inside the foreach loop?

Comment: You need all the values to use `join`. You can just include a colon in the print, but then you will add an extra colon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative for code simplicity you can use **hashref** to an **array** for fruits.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($fruit,$item,$count);

for( split(',',<DATA>) ) {
        ($item,$count) = split('=',$_);
        push @{$fruit->{$item}}, $count;
}

say "My ratio = " . join(':', @{$fruit->{apple}});

__DATA__
apple=1,apple=2
```

Output

```
My ratio = 1:2
```